# EditText equals

Tags: java, equals

I have a search app that only has 150 files. So if somebody searches for 151, it would say *"the file 151 can't be found"*.

I have the code:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

if (edit.getText().toString().equals("151")) {
    edit.setError("Invalid File Name");
} else {
    // Do nothing;
}
```

But I have 2 questions:

1. How can I set `.equals("151")` to something like: `.equals("151" >)` (151 and up)?
2. What is the code of: "Do nothing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You create an int from the string. Like this:

   ```
   int aInt = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());

   if(aInt > 150)
   dostuff();
   ```
2. To do nothing, just add ";".

   ```
   if(foo)
   dostuff();
   else
   ;
   ```

Comment: You're welcome. But as Trev16v mentioned, you must be prepared to catch a numberformatexception. What this means is that if a user enters "foo" and you try to parse that string to an int, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the `EditText`'s value to an Integer, so you can compare it using the operators. Like so:

```
    if (Integer.valueOf(edit.getText().toString()) > 150 ) {do stuff;})
```

You probably want to first parse it (inside a try catch block), then do if/else depending on whether or not the value is within range. For showing a quick validation message to the user you probably want to use a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) notification.

Comment: No this doesnt work; It says:     The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

Comment: whoops, missed a parenthesis, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it that way

```
int num = Integer.parse(edit.getText().toString());
if(num >= 151) {

} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it as an integer and you also need to handle the case where the string cannot be parsed as an integer. You MUST be prepared to catch the NumberFormatException if the value is coming from user input!

```
try{    
    int i = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());

    if(i>150){
        // Do stuff if i > 150
    }
    else{
        // Stuff if i < 151
    }

}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // Deal with the fact that the file name is not a valid integer number (e.g. "ABC")
}
```